# MySQL Database Error: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

Please see below query, I'm stuck trying to update one table from another table that seems to have duplicates.

What will be the correct way to run this statement?

```
UPDATE doc SET idx2 = (SELECT imp.idx2 FROM imp WHERE imp.idx1 = doc.idx1),
idx3 = (SELECT imp.idx3 FROM imp WHERE imp.idx1 = doc.idx1)
WHERE doc.boxid IN (SELECT box.id FROM box WHERE box.profid = 41 
AND box.boxname = '1153-BATCH0011') AND doc.idx2 = ''
```

Comment: The correct way would be to have subquery return exactly 1 row, as per the error message.

Comment: Hi, not quite understanding. Please could show me were im going wrong in the Query I posted.

Comment: I don't know which query returns more than 1 row, that's up to you to find out and fix your query model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're are sure the subqueries are returning duplicate same values, you can just use LIMIT 1 this way your subqueries will return 1 result only.

```
UPDATE doc SET idx2 = (SELECT imp.idx2 FROM imp WHERE imp.idx1 = doc.idx1 LIMIT 1),
idx3 = (SELECT imp.idx3 FROM imp WHERE imp.idx1 = doc.idx1 LIMIT 1)
WHERE doc.boxid IN (SELECT box.id FROM box WHERE box.profid = 41 
AND box.boxname = '1153-BATCH0011') AND doc.idx2 = ''
```

Comment: This works great thank you, never used the Limit 1 function, will have to study up on this. Thank you